# on first button press state is not updating but function called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

on first button press onChange method function is called but state is not updating as it should and on second button press it is updating see this

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
function MainHeader(props) {
    const [FirstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
    const [User, setUser] = useState({
        FirstName: '',
        LastName: ''
    })
    const nameOnChange = (event) => {
        setFirstName(event.target.value)
        console.log(FirstName)
    }
    const addName = () => {
        setUser({
            ...User,
            FirstName: FirstName
        })
        console.log(User)
        props.addUserToFirebase(User)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Checking</h1>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => nameOnChange(e)} value={FirstName}  />
            <button onClick={() => addName()}>Enter</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

on nameOnChange it is console.log(FirstName) when first time a pressed something then console logs empty state (initial state) and on second button it updates the previous button pressed. I have tried creating class component as well but i am seeing the same issue , same thing happens in the addName function it updates state on second click .
see console 
[image]

Comment: I don't see a problem here

Comment: hmm... in the input field when you enter for-example a then what you see in the console ?

Comment: I explained in detail in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem here. It is working perfectly as it should be. But the only problem I see is your wrong understanding of how React works or how Functional Programming works in general.

**There's no mutation in Functional Programming**

```js
    const nameOnChange = (event) => {
        // event => new value
        // FirstName => old value
        // they remain that way throughout this function call

        setFirstName(event.target.value)
        // even if you set the state, the values won't change
        // they will be updated only in next function call

        console.log(FirstName) // still old value
    }
```

The same goes for `addName()`

For each re-render React call the function `MainHeader` with values that will not be mutated throughout their call or life. When value are updated, React will call `MainHeader` with the updated the values.

#### Correct way of using your Component

**Works, but not better way**

```js
const addName = () => {
  setUser({
     ...User,
     FirstName: FirstName
   })

   //
   console.log({
     ...User,
     FirstName: FirstName
   }) // new value, since User is not mutated, User will still have the old value
   props.addUserToFirebase(({
     ...User,
     FirstName: FirstName
   })
 }
```

**Better way**

Always use useEffects for side effects.

```js
// Just set the state
const addName = () => {
  setUser({
     ...User,
     FirstName: FirstName
   })
}

// handle side effects here

useEffect(() => {
    // check is needed here, since it will be
    // called on component's first mount
    if(User.FirstName !== ''){
          console.log(User)
          props.addUserToFirebase(User)
    }
}, [User])

// This will be called whenever React detects a change in `User`
```

Answer (score 1):

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

You must use `useEffect()`.

```
const nameOnChange = (event) => {
    setFirstName(event.target.value)
}

useEffect(()=>{
    if(FirstName !== ''){
         console.log(FirstName)
    }
}, [FirstName])

const addName = () => {
    setUser({
        ...User,
        FirstName: FirstName
    })
}

useEffect(()=>{
    if(User.FirstName !== '' && User.LastName !== ''){
          console.log(User)
          props.addUserToFirebase(User)
    }
}, [User])
```

Comment: dont you think for setting simple state this is a very long solution ? i know this type solution actually but  want to something more better ...

Comment: As I understand it when you call a set function (that was defined by useState) "React will then re-render the ...component, passing the new ...value to it." This is how the new function-component hooks work. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: ...so if you want access to the state you have just updated you need to handle that in the next render of the component. And that's where useEffect comes into play.